# Meaning of the statement with the phrase "until after"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here it is:

> Understood and mastered means that: During the pull from the floor, the bar never leaves the skin of your legs. Your elbows stay straight **until after** the jump.

Does that mean that elbows must be straight until the jump, and after it, or that they must be straight until the jump, but it is normal to bend them after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Until after' means until the given moment, including the moment. There's a state (something that lasts quite long, 'elbows straight') and a moment/event (a short thing, 'the jump'). Without the qualifier, it's unclear if the 'state' may end right before or during the short 'event'. 'You must wear the badges until after you cleared the security checkpoint' - means you can take them off once you've been allowed through. If it was 'You must wear the badges until the security checkpoint' someone may take their badge off right as they enter the checkpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Once the jump has been made, it's okay to bend your elbows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you quoting from "*Starting Strength - Basic Barbell Training*" by Mark Rippetoe? You could include that reference in your question. Notice that it includes photos. According to those images, it seems that you have to maintain your elbows straight until the **beginning** of the jump but you have to bend them if you want to put the bar over your shoulders.

I guess that you **start** jumping and **simultaneously** you start pulling. But I'm no expert in that field. I didn't exactly know when you decide that a jump has finished so you can do something **after** it. When you are at the uppest point in the air or when you have returned to the floor?

Comment: Yes, it is from Starting Strength